# How do I interpret the results from xtprobit random effects model with robust standard errors in stata?

Tags: stata, random-effects-model, probit, robust-standard-error

[image]

My probit model has panel data. The dependent variable is a binary outcome that survives = 1 and not survives = 0. I am estimating South Africa's export trade relationships that are import-product specific.
I did a Cox model (cross-sectional data) before but my Schoenfeld test said there is proportionality in my model therefore I changed to the probit model. However, I do not fully understand how to interpret this model from start to finish. I am finding very little help in the Stata help file with `xtprobit` and postestimation options.

Comment: Non-Stata users as well as Stata users can find the **manual entry** at https://www.stata.com/manuals/xtxtprobit.pdf and the **help file** at https://www.stata.com/help.cgi?xtprobit The primary aim for a help file is to explain how to use a command. The manual entry says more.

Comment: Hi Nick thanks for the feedback but as I said before I am not familiar with this model (first time using it) and it is very different from the Cox model. I would like some guidance or someone to explain to me how to interpret these results. The help file and manuals I find difficult to understand especially when it comes to interpreting.

Comment: The main point of my first comment was to explain the resources available to others. I haven't used this method or ever run this command, so I exclude myself from answering. However, on "how do I interpret the results" I have posted advice to disambiguate at https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3175/top-k-list-of-reasons-to-close-a-question-immediately/4554#4554

Comment: Hi Nick I completely understand the advice you've posted. I will rephrase my question and post again. Thanks